# npm Overlay-navbar can't show icon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web, navbar

I used Navbar, but the icons are not showing, :((

[thist my web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnxJX.png)
[this my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7MXC.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

For any one facing this issue. there are 2 steps to be followed to get the icons to show in the navbar

**STEP 1**

```
import { ReactNavbar } from "overlay-navbar";
import {MdAccountCircle } from "react-icons/md";
import {MdSearch } from "react-icons/md";
import {MdAddShoppingCart } from "react-icons/md";
```

**STEP 2** Within add as shown below

```
<ReactNavbar
  profileIcon:true,
  profileIconColor: "rgba(35, 35, 35,0.8)",
  ProfileIconElement: MdAccountCircle, 
  searchIcon:true,
  searchIconColor: "rgba(35, 35, 35,0.8)",
  SearchIconElement:MdSearch,
  cartIcon:true,
  cartIconColor: "rgba(35, 35, 35,0.8)",
  CartIconElement:MdAddShoppingCart,
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `"overlay-navbar": "^1.2.3"` and `"react-icons": "^4.2.0"` on `package.json`

and pass `profileIcon={true} ProfileIconElement={FaUserAlt}`

This worked for me